# Maximize size of Android button text

Tags: android, button

I had multiple buttons in a LinearLayout horizontally. On a larger device all the button text fit on one line at 20sp text size. However, on a smaller device at 20sp text size, the text of the buttons goes to two lines.

How can I tell it to make the text size as big as possible so that text stays on one line?

Comment: Have you tried setting the maximum lines property to 1?

Comment: Yes, but that does not work as then it just cots off the letters that would go on the second line. I need the text to be resized when there isn't enough space, not for the text to be truncated.

Comment: Ah I see, it sounds the property `singleLine` will be more what you are looking for.

Comment: Nope, now it puts "..." at the end instead, not resizing the text.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me ... you will need to customize for your needs:

```
// Determine Scaled Density for later calculations
Display dd = ((Activity) m_Context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
dd.getMetrics(dm);
float m_ScaledDensity = dm.scaledDensity;

Rect bounds = new Rect();
Paint p = new Paint();
p.setTypeface(btn.getTypeface());

// W is a very wide character
String sample = "NeedsToFIt"
int maxFont;
for (maxFont= 1
    ; -bounds.top <= btn.getHeight() && bounds.right <= btn.getWidth()
    ; maxFont++) {
  p.setTextSize(maxFont);
  p.getTextBounds(sample, 0, sample.length(), bounds);
}
maxFont = (int) ((maxFont - 1) / m_ScaledDensity);
btn.setTextSize(maxFont);
```

Comment: Also, this doesn't take into account the button padding.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the screen resolution , and in your code, you can adapt the size of the text of your buttons by changing the `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`

**EDIT : algorithm**

**First** : get the screen resolutions, to see if your phone is a small,meduim or big .(to do this , use  the class : `DisplayMetrics` )

**Second** : in your code , you will test for every type of size ( in general i think 3 : small , meduim,big ) , and modify the textSize of your buttons like this :

```
btn.setTextSize(float size ) ;
```

Comment: How would I adjust the text size based on screen width? What would be the algorithm?

Comment: That won't work, as I already account for different densities using the "sp" size.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that worked for me: [Resize Text to Fit the View in Android](http://catchthecows.com/?p=72)
 [[source code]](https://github.com/catchthecows/BigTextButton/)

In short, override the `onDraw` method to suit your needs.